# Can a search engine follow <button> or <input> elements?

Tags: html, seo

I am considering replacing  links with  such as:

```
<input type="button" onclick ="window.location.href('http://foo.com')" value="Click me!" />
```

There was a suggestion that search engines could not follow this kind of link. Does anyone have any knowledge to confirm this.

thanks,

Comment: As far as I know search engines don't follow buttons. For example, what would they do when crawling an loginform or contactform? They only follow hyperlinks. Judging by your provided example, why not create an hyperlink. Point that to foo.com and style it like an button with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that would be horrible for SEO purposes...

- A button should submit a form, not take you to a new resource.
- Bots have limited knowledge of JavaScript.
- *Click me!* is terrible link text, unless you want to rank for *click* and *me*.

Comment: In general you're of course right. However:
* Whether buttons are used for links is a question of website design, and the `<button>` tag is different from the `<input type="submit" ...>` and `<input type ="button" ...>` tags.
* You don't _have_ to use JavaScript with a "button"ed link. Simply enclose it in a `<a href>`.
* I'm sure _Click me!_ is a placeholder :).

Answer (score 1):

According to [pitstopmedia.com](http://www.pitstopmedia.com/sem/form-tags-seo),

> `<button>`Some text here`</button>` – some text goes here will be indexed by search engines.