# CSS transition with background gradient

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm learning about animations/transitions with CSS3, but in this code the transition don't worked... why?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test {
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #666);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
}

#test:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666, #999);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLRfN/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webkit support for gradient transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790273/webkit-support-for-gradient-transitions) - seems like you're out of luck for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me as it should intended. A couple things, this will only work in google chrome if you want it to work in other browsers:

[Here is a generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

[Here is an explanation](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)

**edit**

Sorry I didn't realize there was a `transition` property in there. After doing some googling and trying some stuff out on my own, it is pretty clear that transitions on background gradients isn't possible... yet.

Here is a good article on how to get it to work with a little bit of a hack

http://nimbupani.com/some-css-transition-hacks.html

Answer (score 0):

its working fine on me. have you wrapped the css file with  tag?

```
<style>
#test {
background-color: #333;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #666);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
}

#test:hover {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666, #999);
}
</style>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Realy?! I've tested in Chrome and Safari but don't the transition effect don't worked ):

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, Also I can point you to the CSS3 playground where you can check it on the fly 
 
  [CSS3 Playground](http://css3.mikeplate.com)

Answer (score 0):

Gradient transition can by done with little bit of "cheating". I am definitely not pro in css stuff (and I am new here so don't hate me fast :D ), but just place to divs on top of each other, one with opacity 1 and second with 0.
(Each div has set different gradients) On hover, change opacity from 1 to 0 and vice versa.

Set timing function and however these divs are placed on each other z-index property do the rest. 
(Optimized for Safari) Maybe rookie way, but this works (surprisingly) perfectly:

```
 #divgradient1
    {
     z-index:-1;
     height:100px;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue); 
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);

     opacity:1;
     transition:background,opacity,z-index;
     -webkit-transition:background,opacity,z-index ;
     transition-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    }

 #divgradient1:hover{
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;        
    transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    -webkit-transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    }


 #divgradient2:hover{
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, blue);
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, blue);
    transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    -webkit-transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
    }


 #divgradient2
    {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    height:100px;        
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, blue);
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, blue);
    transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    -webkit-transition:background,opacity,z-index;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    }
```

and whatever-it-should-look-like divs:

```
    <div id="divgradient1" style="position:absolute;width:100px;"></div>
    <div id="divgradient2" style="position:absolute;width:100px;"></div>
```