# css3 ( transition ) not working

Tags: css

I am trying to change the background and text color with the css3 transition effects when hovering over a button, but only the text color is changing and not the background color. Here is my jsfiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/HjvmY/)   and here is my css :

```
.input-submit
{
    margin: 12px 0 2px
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(255, 255, 255)), to(rgb(224, 224, 224)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(224, 224, 224));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(224, 224, 224));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(224, 224, 224));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(224, 224, 224));
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    border-image: initial;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.input-submit:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 12px 0 2px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(145, 191, 1)), to(rgb(111, 149, 1)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(145, 191, 1), rgb(111, 149, 1));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(145, 191, 1), rgb(111, 149, 1));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(145, 191, 1), rgb(111, 149, 1));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(145, 191, 1), rgb(111, 149, 1));
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    border-image: initial;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: Works for me... edit: Oh, I see. It's not transitioning...

Comment: Alex appears to be right, see the answer the user gave for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790273/webkit-support-for-gradient-transitions

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a block of CSS you've got there! As far as I'm aware, no browsers allow transitions of css gradients yet. Since your backgrounds aren't solid colors, you can't transition them.