# jQuery - Fading body background (css gradient) into another CSS gradient

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've been jQuery'ing a little while, but i can't figure out how i would fade from one gradient to another. I have been using
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
for my gradients. and for example

```
background: #ffaf4b;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffaf4b 0%, #ff920a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffaf4b), color-stop(100%,#ff920a));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffaf4b 0%,#ff920a 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffaf4b 0%,#ff920a 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffaf4b 0%,#ff920a 100%);
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffaf4b 0%,#ff920a 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffaf4b', endColorstr='#ff920a',GradientType=1 );
```

So if i wanted to on click of a link fade between multiple gradients how would you go about it?
(I would be using it for Navigation and/or div backgrounds)

At the moment i have been trying to store the above code in a var and use

```
$('.li1').click(function(){
$('.navBar').animate(bgVar, 3000);
});
```

Thanks in advance
Mach

Comment: You might find some useful suggestions in this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790273/webkit-support-for-gradient-transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using background gradient you can use two large `DIV`with two different gradient placed behind everything, one on top of the other. To do the transition, `fadeOut` the bottom one and `fadeIn` the top one using the same duration. http://jsfiddle.net/CeD2q/6/

Comment: Using this method. Used 4 divs with different gradients all with
    .class{position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}
work's well lets hope they change it, so it can be done easier :)

Thanks
Mach

Answer (score 0):

I think that currently transitioning from a background gradient to another background gradient is impossible. I have seen some people circumvent this by using a large gradient background-image or a background gradient and then transitioning using the background-position property.

Example here:
http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/